# Dart override equality operator on sub objects?

Tags: flutter, dart

With the DART language, If I have a mix of objects like...

```
class Leg {
}

class Arm {
}

class Body {
  Leg _leg;
  Arm _arm;
}
```

If I want to override the equality operator in 'Body', do I need to override the equality operator in 'Arm' and 'Body' as well?

Comment: Your title mentions the the assignment-operator ('='), do you mean the equality-operator ('==') instead?

Comment: is this a question about what you _should_ do (best-practice) or about what you _must_ do (language specification)?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

You could just compare the members of the `Arm` am `Leg` like this:

```dart
class Leg {
  const Leg(this.length);
  
  final int length;
}

class Arm {
  const Arm(this.isBruised);
  
  final bool isBruised;
}

class Body {
  const Body(this._leg, this._arm);
  
  final Leg _leg;
  final Arm _arm;
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other is! Body) {
      return false;
    }
    
    final legsAreEqual = _leg.length == other._leg.length;
    final armsAreEqual = _arm.isBruised == other._arm.isBruised;
    
    return legsAreEqual && armsAreEqual;
  }
  
  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(_arm, _leg);
}
```

Though if `Arm` and `Leg` contained more properties, it might be a good idea to override the operator in those classes instead as you initially suggested.
It separates the comparison logic and makes the classes more generally reusable.

Comment: hashCode is inconsistent with `==`, this will lead to ugly bugs.

Comment: @julaine that's my bad. Didn't wanted to make the example longer than it needed to be.